# FCM only sends message in tray when app is killed but i need notifications with sound

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using a simple example of firebase messaging I found from example section of firebase_messaging package.

main.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Map<String, Item> _items = <String, Item>{};
Item _itemForMessage(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
  final dynamic data = message['data'] ?? message;
  final String itemId = data['id'];
  final Item item = _items.putIfAbsent(itemId, () => Item(itemId: itemId))
    ..status = data['status'];
  return item;
}

class Item {
  Item({this.itemId});
  final String itemId;

  StreamController<Item> _controller = StreamController<Item>.broadcast();
  Stream<Item> get onChanged => _controller.stream;

  String _status;
  String get status => _status;
  set status(String value) {
    _status = value;
    _controller.add(this);
  }

  static final Map<String, Route<void>> routes = <String, Route<void>>{};
  Route<void> get route {
    final String routeName = '/detail/$itemId';
    return routes.putIfAbsent(
      routeName,
      () => MaterialPageRoute<void>(
        settings: RouteSettings(name: routeName),
        builder: (BuildContext context) => DetailPage(itemId),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  DetailPage(this.itemId);
  final String itemId;
  @override
  _DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  Item _item;
  StreamSubscription<Item> _subscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _item = _items[widget.itemId];
    _subscription = _item.onChanged.listen((Item item) {
      if (!mounted) {
        _subscription.cancel();
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _item = item;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Item ${_item.itemId}"),
      ),
      body: Material(
        child: Center(child: Text("Item status: ${_item.status}")),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PushMessagingExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PushMessagingExampleState createState() => _PushMessagingExampleState();
}

class _PushMessagingExampleState extends State<PushMessagingExample> {
  String _homeScreenText = "Waiting for token...";
  bool _topicButtonsDisabled = false;

  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  final TextEditingController _topicController =
      TextEditingController(text: 'topic');

  Widget _buildDialog(BuildContext context, Item item) {
    return AlertDialog(
      content: Text("Item ${item.itemId} has been updated"),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: const Text('CLOSE'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, false);
          },
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: const Text('SHOW'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context, true);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void _showItemDialog(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => _buildDialog(context, _itemForMessage(message)),
    ).then((bool shouldNavigate) {
      if (shouldNavigate == true) {
        _navigateToItemDetail(message);
      }
    });
  }

  void _navigateToItemDetail(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    final Item item = _itemForMessage(message);
    // Clear away dialogs
    Navigator.popUntil(context, (Route<dynamic> route) => route is PageRoute);
    if (!item.route.isCurrent) {
      Navigator.push(context, item.route);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
        _showItemDialog(message);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        _navigateToItemDetail(message);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        _navigateToItemDetail(message);
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(
            sound: true, badge: true, alert: true, provisional: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      setState(() {
        _homeScreenText = "Push Messaging token: $token";
      });
      print(_homeScreenText);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Push Messaging Demo'),
        ),
        // For testing -- simulate a message being received
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () => _showItemDialog(<String, dynamic>{
            "data": <String, String>{
              "id": "2",
              "status": "out of stock",
            },
          }),
          tooltip: 'Simulate Message',
          child: const Icon(Icons.message),
        ),
        body: Material(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Text(_homeScreenText),
              ),
              Row(children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                      controller: _topicController,
                      onChanged: (String v) {
                        setState(() {
                          _topicButtonsDisabled = v.isEmpty;
                        });
                      }),
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: const Text("subscribe"),
                  onPressed: _topicButtonsDisabled
                      ? null
                      : () {
                          _firebaseMessaging
                              .subscribeToTopic(_topicController.text);
                          _clearTopicText();
                        },
                ),
                FlatButton(
                  child: const Text("unsubscribe"),
                  onPressed: _topicButtonsDisabled
                      ? null
                      : () {
                          _firebaseMessaging
                              .unsubscribeFromTopic(_topicController.text);
                          _clearTopicText();
                        },
                ),


----------


              ])
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }

  void _clearTopicText() {
    setState(() {
      _topicController.text = "";
      _topicButtonsDisabled = true;
    });
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: PushMessagingExample(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Everything works fine but notification is not appearing as I want.
I need notification like the following:

it appears for like 2-3 secs and then we can check it in tray if we ignore it.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfeSd.png

but instead of this i'm just getting flutter icon beside clock at the top bar and i have to drag and check tray to check notification.

So, please let me know how to show notification with sound and small banner at the top which should appear for some seconds and then if notification is ignored should stay in tray.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have done as what's mentioned in the official doc but trust me the official doc is so dead and incomplete.

You need to follow a few steps to show notification banners:

**Source and credits:** https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1327#issuecomment-623399564

Add the following to your `strings.xml`. Of course, you'll want to customize these for your own app and be aware that the channel name and channel description are what the user will see in their notification settings.

```
<string name="notification_channel_id" translatable="false">my_unique_fcm_id</string>
<string name="notification_channel_name">The name of this notification</string>
<string name="notification_channel_desc">A description of the notification.</string>
```

Register the new notification channel by adding the following code to your app. This should be done as early as possible, for example, after calling super.onCreate in `MainActivity.kt` (or .java).

```
// Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
// the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
     val channelID = getString(R.string.notification_channel_id)
     val name = getString(R.string.notification_channel_name)
     val descriptionText = getString(R.string.notification_channel_desc)
     val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
     val channel = NotificationChannel(channelID, name, importance).apply {
          description = descriptionText
      }
      // Register the channel with the system
      val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
           getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
      notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
}
```

Pay attention to the line which sets the importance, as this is what causes notifications sent on this channel to appear as a "Heads Up" notification.

```
val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
```

Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml under the  tag. This will ensure that any FCM's sent without a notification channel set in their payload will use this one. `(optional)`

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id" android:value="@string/notification_channel_id" />
```

Clean and rebuild

Send a test FCM. It should use your newly created channel by default and show up as a "Heads Up" notification.

(Optional) You can repeat these steps to set up more notification channels for each type of notification you plan on sending. Just make sure each has a unique ID, and that you bundle the channel ID with the notification payload when you send it.
The full docs are here.

Comment: But i need name and description dynamic @OMiShah. There should be a way to do this without editing android code. some people suggested flutter_local_notifications with firebase_messaging but i don't know how to implement both?

Comment: man, the process I shared it to register notification channel with the highest priority which will enable you to send notification from FCM with sound and head up notification as you're looking for.

Once you have done the basic, you just need to pass the channel id with your notification payload which will play sound and show notification on the user's device.

Comment: It works, finally!  I had to check out the documentation from the official site for kotlin code also I had to check out some examples, so @OMiShah 's answer is correct but people who don't know anything about android cannot get their head around this very easily.

Comment: Thank God you understood brother 